# Boolean operation on 2 almost identical objects

Tags: modifiers

I have two almost identical objects, let's say two spheres. They are perfectly aligned. The second sphere has a small hollow. For illustration I move them next to each other here:

[image: two UV spheres]

I want to get only the missing volume, so I add a boolean operation on sphere 1 like this :

[image: Bad boolean operation]

The result is wrong, but if I scale sphere 1 down just a little, the result is correct:

[image: Good boolean but with scale down]

Why? Is there a way to get the expected result without having to scale down the first object?

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which Blender version are you using? Or maybe it's just because you are on Mac, but if I open the provided blend file it works just as expected without scaling down one sphere. I'm on Windows and using Blender 3.0.0

Comment: I am on Mac with Blender Version 2.90.0 (2.90.0 2020-08-31). I just tried the same file on a Windows PC, with blender 2.93.2 , and indeed, it does work as expected without having to change the scale. Thx for pointing this out, it may be a mac issue then ...

Comment: I updated my Mac Blender to 3.0.0 , problem solved ! , Thx again !

Comment: * Solved for these two sphere, on my photogrammetry model, even when remeshed , it still can't handle all the overlapping geometry ...

Comment: @iliès you were right, changing the threshold doen't do much, it's due to the old boolean solver, they improved it since 2.91.

Comment: @iliès It is always helpful when asking questions to mention which version you are using if you are not on the current stable version. Because people using the most recent version might not be able to reproduce your problem if it is version specific. Of course it self-evident when I'm looking at old questions that people had older versions when they were asking, but it is not explicitly clear when I'm looking at newest questions that the asker is using a (much) older version.

Comment: Boolean operations are always tricky when working with complex meshes that maybe have bad geometry as well, especially photogrammetry meshes often look a mess. So it's not unusual the _Boolean Modifier_ will have a hard time solving this and might fail.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes. Whan I saw this question, I tried to reproduce it with 3.0 and 2.93 and since I obtained normal results I thought the only explanation was that the spheres were not exactly the same.. I guess I need to be more careful :D

Answer (score 0):

I appears to me that your sphere 1 is a bit larger than sphere 2 so when you set the operation to difference, you have this :

[image]

That also explained why you have the intended result only when scaling it down.

You can solve this by playing with the `Overlap Threshold` value.

**EDIT**

It seems to be an issue with the boolean itself and I believe the issue have been fixed since 2.91 where they improved the booleans as stated in the [2.91 release notes](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-91/).

I took a look on the uploaded file and applied the boolean modifier in 2.93 and 3.0 and this is what I got :

-In **2.93**

[image]
[image]

-And in **3.0**

[image]
[image]

However, this is what I have when I used the same spheres in **2.79** :

[image]
[image]

Notice that **2.93** and **3.0** don't have the `Overlap Threshold` option anymore. And you were right : tweaking that option didn't change the result at all.

In **2.79**, changing the solver from `Bmesh` to `Carve` solves the problem :

[image]
[image]

But that option is gone since **2.8**+ so I think you may want to try the newer versions of Blender to see if this solves your problem?

Comment: Sphere 1 and Sphere 2 are exactly the same size, I just duplicated sphere 1 and I applied a small negative "Clay Thumb" in "Sculpt mode" on sphere 2. I tried playing with the "Overlap Threshold" , it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Could you upload to Blend file then? The picture below is just for illustration but the difference between you meshes don't need to be that big to cause this result. The overlap threshold is `0.000001 m` which means that if you meshes differ by just 0.001 millimeters in diameter, Blender will consider one of them bigger and that amount of difference could have been easily cause by your sculpt.

Comment: @iliès I only get a message "The file you requested has been deleted" when trying to download it.

Comment: here is the file on google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PFAboGAvSWJj2NLgwV0iq6wX_i9WIECH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't download the file for some reason. I don't see the message @Gordon sees but I can't download it.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Now I can download it, I've edited the question to properly provide the file there.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean operations just don't work correctly if you have overlapping geometry. Scaling down one of the objects just a little is the correct solution for this situation. If you do not want to change the result of the operation, you can only move the overlapping geometry a little bit in edit mode, until the operation works. You could try switching between Fast and "Exact" modes of the operator as well to see if it makes a difference in the specific situation, but in most cases, you will have to make sure objects don't have overlapping geometry when using Booleans for them to work correctly. This is not only a problem in Blender, this is a problem with the math used in the algorithms.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the clarification. That's a problem for me because I am trying to get the before / after use on object that I 3d Scan with photogrammetry, to find damaged parts on the object. Any idea on how to achieve this without boolean operation ? (Also, there is no Fast/Exact mode on the Mac version of Blender)

Comment: Scaling down the object doesn't work well on photogrammetry model, too many overlapping geometry appear in the middle and a lot of artefacts.

Comment: I don't think anything works on photogrammetry. If it's noisy or has problems, you need better photos, more precise processing. I use photogrammetry a lot and as far as I know, the only way is to either make the reconstruction detailed enough to use as is, or to manually retopologies it. That's always a pain.

Comment: @iliès Are you sure there is no Fast/Exact mode on the Mac version? The Blender manual doesn't mention that... maybe you are just using an older version of Blender? The _Boolean Modifier_ first got these options in 2.91 and also was improved overall - so maybe you should update your Blender.